# Django project works locally but not when deployed to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

Django project works locally but not when deployed to Heroku.

I'm getting this error:

```
ImportError at /

No module named 'inkbook.urls'
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value: No module named 'inkbook.urls'
```

(Yes, I still have DEBUG=True, I know I'll need to change this.)

Python 3.5.1

My requirements.txt

```
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.10.4
gunicorn==19.6.0
whitenoise==3.2.2
psycopg2==2.6.2
```

I followed this guide:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python

and this one:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration

When I run `heroku local web` localhost:5000 functions perfectly.

I've deployed using `git push heroku master` but get the above error when I go to the actual live website.

Here's the url to the App that is giving me issue. I'm not sure if there is anything in there that is the problem though, I suspect it might be someplace else:
github.com/desult/inkbook

I have found similar issues and the solution for some have been to edit `ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'` to `ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'` . That doesn't seem to work for me, nor does it make sense that it would work.

My Root urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^inkbook/', include('inkbook.urls', namespace='inkbook')),
]
```

My inkbook.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'), ]
```

When I remove 'inkbook' from INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and remove `url(r'^inkbook/', include('inkbook.urls', namespace='inkbook'))` from urls.py, the site works. I suspect it has something to do with include, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try doing `url(r'^inkbook/', include('project_name.inkbook.urls', namespace='inkbook')),`

Comment: That still gives me an Import Error, this time No module named 'mysite.inkbook'

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` file in `inkbook` directory?

Comment: Yes, the __init__.py file is in place. With under scores, not sure why they are not showing.